# What tags should I use when asking a Qt 4 question, using C++?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Which of [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [qt](/questions/tagged/qt), and [qt4](/questions/tagged/qt4) should I use? All? Some? What if I am not sure that my problem has anything to do with that version of Qt?

Comment: there are other users who can edit the question with proper tag, when you have doubts in tags. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and the [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) tags. From the [qt4](/questions/tagged/qt4) tag excerpt:

> Questions specifically about version 4.x of the Qt GUI library. If your question applies to other versions of Qt, use the tag [qt].

Since you are not sure if your question needs the [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) tag at all, better stick with that advice and not use a version-specific tag.

I wouldn't worry *too* much about what tags to use though; experienced users are happy to retag your question if they feel it could do with better labelling.

Answer (score 0):

For me as a reader from Qt and c++ those 'c++' and 'qt' are the used tags to follow new questions.